# maven dependency for play.filters.cors.CORSFilter

Tags: java, playframework, lagom

I am trying to add a CORS Filter to my Lagom Framework REST API. I added a Filters class, as per the documentation, however it cannot  to find the  package for CROSSFilter. Need MAVEN dependency flay framework CrossFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need filters helper package

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>filters-helpers_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Different versions:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/filters-helpers_2.11
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/filters-helpers_2.10

API Docs:

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.typesafe.play/filters-helpers_2.11/2.5.13